# Issue with some accented letters in Ubuntu 22.04 and Sublime Text 4

Tags: ubuntu, xfce, sublimetext4

My problem is, when I try to write 'Í', 'í', 'ó', or 'Ó', these doesn't work. 'í' only put Sublime Text in full screen, 'Í' something like this:

[I don't know how to call it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYGzl.jpg)

'ñ' only goes at the end of the line. And 'ó' and 'Ó' does nothing in the current file. No insert, no window changes, only does nothing.

I checked my Key Binding and I didn't find anything important. I tested Those letters in other Apps and work perfectly. It's only in Sublime Text window. Others like 'á', 'Á' and anothers works perfectly too.

Comment: What keyboard layout are you using?

Comment: This is I found running `cat /etc/default/keyboard`: `# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="latam"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS=""

BACKSPACE="guess"`

Comment: I'm not sure what all that means, but "latam" makes it sound like Latin American Spanish, yeah?

Comment: Yeah. Natively I speak Spanish. I changed the layout from "latam" to "us" and I ran `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`. It works now.

Comment: this should be asked at https://askubuntu.com/ or https://superuser.com